# R ggplot2: continous scale based on index

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataframe (94k+ values) with lat/lon values. Short example:

```
df <- data.frame(lat = c(50, 60, 70, 80, 90), 
                 lon = c(25, 28, 30, 32, 35))
```

But because the original dataframe is so large, I want to fill in the colour of the plotted points (with geom_point) based on the index value. So it shows the path of the observations over time with a gradient.

Current ggplot:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat)
```

Comment: Could you include some of the other data required to plot this? I would guess dates. When you say index do you mean a grouping variable or do you mean the position of elements of the dataframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an index:

```
df$index <- 1:nrow(df)
```

Graph:

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = index))
```

Comment: But does this add the colour gradient I asked about? I can do this, but it does cause the full dataframe of 90k+ entities to get much larger. Ggplot won't be too happy with this

Comment: It should add a colour gradient, yes, since index is numeric rather than factor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for such a solution?

```
df <- data.frame(lat = c(50, 60, 70, 80, 90), 
                 lon = c(25, 28, 30, 32, 35))

library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(id_as_index = row_number())

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, color=factor(id_as_index))) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw ()
```

[image]